# my bindable function is spitting out the error "attempt to call a nil value"?

Tags: lua, roblox

for a roblox lua game.

I'm trying to make a bindable function that after the player clicks on the text box, types something in, and then clicks enter/return it stores the word in the server and then prints it in the output. Now everything on the typing side works, It even prints out on a surfacegui. The problem is that if I try to run the code I get the error "attempt to call a nil value". Here's my Invoke code for typing in the box.

```
local screenTextBox = script.Parent -- Location of Textbox on the screen
local partTextLabel = game.Workspace.BlueTeamGameRoom.BlueGameBoard.Board.SurfaceGui.TextBox -- Location of text on block

while true do --code to update the screengui
    wait(.5)--wait in order to keep roblox studio from crapping itself
screenTextBox.FocusLost:connect()--for clicking on the textbox
    partTextLabel.Text = screenTextBox.Text -- Change text
end


screenTextBox.FocusLost:connect(function(enterPressed) --defining enterpressed(clicking enter) within the parameters of the player clicking the box
    if enterPressed then 
        local DBallz = game.ReplicatedStorage.answerVerify:Invoke() --calling the bindable function

        print(DBallz)--printing what the bindable function returns
    end
end)
```

and here's my OnInvoke code to print the word in the box

```
game.ReplicatedStorage.answerVerify.OnInvoke = function()
    local Text = game.StarterGui.ScreenGui.wordSend.TextBox.Text --defining the property of the text of the textbox
    
    return Text --sending the text to the local script
end
```

I've tried using InvokeServer and OnServerInvoke but there was no difference. There I also tried using a different way of writing the keycode mapping but that didn't work either. and also the invoke code is in a localScript that is a child of the text box the user has to type in. and the on invoke code is in a regular server-side script that's a child of the workspace.

Comment: errors like that come with a stack trace, a line number and a name. so which nil value are you trying to call? pleaser read [ask]

Comment: @Piglet Well first off, oddly enough the error didn't come with a stack trace, line number, or name but Looking at it now it doesn't seem like the nil value is my issue because if I press enter anywhere within the text box it'll say attempt to call a nil value. even without using enterPressed

Answer (score 0):

In your code I see this:

```
screenTextBox.FocusLost:connect()
```

You should provide a function here. So a soon as your textbox loses focus Roblox will call the event listener which happens to be nil.

Why do you do this in a loop btw? That doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: I think you're focusing on the wrong thing. The one you're talking about right now is the code to constantly update the screengui. that's why it's in a loop. That one works, the problem I'm having is with the one below it. That's the one that's supposed to send the word to the server. I'll comment that to make it clearer.

Comment: so what happens in your opinion when you connect an event to a nil value? `connect` has been deprecated for many years btw. it is not even documented anymore. Use `Connect` instead. From my understanding this nil value will be called as soon as the event is being fired. and what is the purpose of that loop? connecting an Event listener multiple times, especially in an ininite loop makes no sense to me. and the second part of your code is never reached as you're stuck in that infinite loop. so if I'm focussing on the wrong part of your code you might as well just delete it from your question.

Comment: Ok well like I said earlier the for loop is to constantly be pinging the client so the the surfacegui can put the word they're typing on the board at all times. But I'd like to ask you to elaborate further on what you mean by the code being stuck in an infinite loop

Comment: you run a while loop that connects a nil value to an event (useless), updates a text ( useful) and waits (-> returns control back to Roblox for a while) anything after that loop is never executed as you never leave that loop. there is no break nor can the condition ever fail.

Comment: Ok, wait that seems like that might work. I'm just trying to figure exactly how I can implement it to work. Thanks for the help.